# Can't pass an argument in html when using php within

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm currently experiencing an issue with a piece of code. I'm getting the results of an SQL query and placing them in an HTML table. This all works perfectly. However, in each row, there is a button which will change their status from "active" to "revoked". I originally planned on sending their unique number into a function and then using PHP it would change the status.

This is seems very do-able but I cannot pass an argument in the function.

The code below shows a test:

```
<table class="data-table" id="table">
    <caption class="title">Dells Members</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>SELECT</th>
            <th>REVOKE ACCESS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $no     = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $test = "hello";
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['txtFullName'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Status'].'</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value='.$row['txtFullName'].' name='.$row['txtFullName'].'></td>
                <td><button onclick="alert('$test')">Try it</button></td>
            </tr>';
        $no++;
    }?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

if you have a look at the button line, i currently have `alert('$test')` which I tried after realising `myFunction('name here')` didn't work. None of this worked.

However, i know that i can call the function as I tried it without the parameters and it worked fine.

I assume this is an issue with the fact that I'm using an `echo` with ' '.

I have looked around an cannot find anyone else with this problem, or a fix. This is my last resort so hopefully you can help or come up with a work-around.

Comment: When you want a `'` in a single quoted string you have to write `\'`.

Comment: @Progman thank you for this, I tried but now it displays .$test. Rather than “hello” which is stored in the constant $test

Comment: If you write `$` in a single-quoted string, you get exactly that character, please read http://www.php.net/string.

Comment: @Progman I have read this webpage but I still can't seem to get it working, what would you suggest I do to make it work?

Comment: It depends on what code you need on the client/browser side. It could be `'<td><button onclick="alert(\''.$test.'\')">Try it</button></td>'`, but it could also something else. Create a simple HTML page first to see what HTML code you actually want (and which `'` and `"` you want/need), then you can use PHP to generate that output.

Comment: @Progman OH MY GOD you're a genius, thank you so much! i've been stuck on this problem for days!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot. Button line neads to be:

```
<td><button onclick="alert('.$test.')">Try it</button></td>
```

Comment: @HarryB Whats the HTML output in the browser generated in PHP? I am expecting `<button onclick="alert('Hello')">Try it</button>`